# C# ListBox does not recognize that there is a selection

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm new to c# so keep that in mind.

I'm building a c# front-end for a restful webservice and I have a listbox which I have put items into:

```
listBox.DataSource = list;
listBox.DataTextField = "name";
listBox.DataValueField = "id";
listBox.DataBind();
```

Then I select an item and click a button that activates this code:

```
long id = Convert.ToInt64(listBox.SelectedItem.Value);
```

The problem is the SelectedItem is null.

Like I said, I am new to c# so I have no clue what could be wrong.

Comment: When are you databinding?

Comment: First, you need to add some items into listBox, and then you need to click one of them before clicking the button.

Comment: Winform or wpf or Asp.net?

Comment: The databind and adding to the list happens on pageload and all of the items show in the listbox like they should.  Then I click on one and click the button and the debugger comes up and I go through each element and the SelectedItem is the one coming back null.  And it is winform

Comment: Do you have any items within your listbox? If so, show us the code for it and we may be able to help out

Comment: Wrap binding code in `if(!Page.IsPostBack){binding code here}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Page_Load` event, do this:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    listBox.DataSource = list;
    listBox.DataTextField = "name";
    listBox.DataValueField = "id";
    listBox.DataBind();
}
```

Note: This will bind your list box the first time the page is loaded and not on every post back, which is what was wiping out your selected item before. In ASP.NET, click event handlers happen after the `Page_Load` event happens, so if you do not put a condition on when you bind, then every post back would wipe out the data before your event handler had a chance to find out what the user selected.

Comment: Thank you, that worked.  I worked on that for way too long. And the explanation helped a lot.

Comment: No problem, it is always the little things that get you with ASP.NET. In the future, when data or selected items are disappearing remember to look for this, because most of the time this is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{    
    listBox.DataSource = list;
    listBox.DataTextField = "name";
    listBox.DataValueField = "id";
    listBox.DataBind();
}
```

This must be in your `Page_Load`.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have correctly coded to prevent creaming your selections on postback, there is another requirement which must be met in order to avoid the same symptoms.  If you supply a DataValueField, the values in that column need to be unique.  See the question [ASP.NET DropDownList not retaining selected item on postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189158/asp-net-dropdownlist-not-retaining-selected-item-on-postback)