# object property not being updated with value from drop down list

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am trying to update a property of an object called `Book`. On the web form, the user makes a selection using a drop down list, and after pressing the `save` button, a postback is triggered to save the data.

Every other property is being saved correctly like title, subject, author, etc, but this one property in the drop down list is never being saved.

I don't get any errors when I trace it, but I see that both the `text` and `value` property of the `ddlSpecialtyName` is empty even though the user has selected a value.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub CreateTest_LoadComplete(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.LoadComplete
    If IsPostBack Then
        Using tran = DbSession.BeginTransaction()
            Book.SpecialtyName = ddlSpecialtyName.SelectedItem.Text
            DbSession.Update(Book)
            tran.Commit()
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

And the ddl control:

```
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSpecialtyName" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: do you have the code for the control

Comment: I added the code for the control. thanks

Comment: "When" do you populate your _databound_ dropdown list? See this [Page lifecyle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4189196/304683) and also [this for Page.LoadComplete](http://forums.asp.net/t/1664002.aspx)...Hth...

Comment: I populate it in CreateTest_Init event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Set the autopostback property to true for dropdown.